# How can I make widgets inside a gridview change size while scrolling?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

I have a gridview (specifically StaggeredGridView) and I want to make the children widgets change size while scrolling to get the effect that the widgets in the middle of the screen are the largest and as the user scrolls and the widget gets out of the screen it shrinks.

Is there a way to implement it or does such a layout already exist?

Comment: Depend on UX complexity and yes you can do that by checking visible widgets on grid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **ScrollController**.
In the code below, the value of **ScrollPoint** will change as you scroll. You can use its value to change the size.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  final dataKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(onScroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  onScroll() {
    setState(() {
      scrollPoint = scrollController.offset;
    });
    print(scrollPoint);
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(onScroll);
    super.dispose();
  }

  double scrollPoint = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(scrollPoint);

    return Scaffold() }}
```

Comment: That's the idea I initially thought about but it seemed too complex to me and I wanted to see if there is a simpler way to do it. Guess I'll use that way after all. Thank you.